# Placing XML Code into layout, pager.xml

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, bitmap

It seems as if I am getting errors for using

**@color/background**, 
**@color/primary_dark**, and 
**@drawable/source_but**.

**`Error:(32, 33) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'background' with value '@color/background').`**

**`Error:(44, 36) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'textColor' with value '@color/primary_dark').`**

**`Error:(121, 33) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'background' with value '@drawable/source_but').`**

I am creating a form inside of the source code of 
https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html

So basically I try to put the textboxes and other objects into:

image_detail_pager.xml under layout folder.

Here's how I try to place the objects:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/background"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            tools:context="com.chalkstreet.learnandroid.main.Form">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewHeader"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="Fill the form and press the button to see the captured data."
                android:textColor="@color/primary_dark"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="Name"
                android:inputType="textPersonName"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textColorHint="#f1434343" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="Email"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textColorHint="#f1434343" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="Password"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textColorHint="#f1434343" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText4"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="Phone"
                android:inputType="phone"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textColorHint="#f1434343" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button_submit"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:text="Submit" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonSrc"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"

            android:background="@drawable/source_but"
            android:text="VIEW SOURCE CODE FOR ACTIVITY" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

.........................................................................

I have updated drawable with source_but.jpg, choosing my own image. And I updated colors.xml. 
Now I have a different error! It seems something is inconsistent here.

```
Error:(34, 24) No resource found that matches the given name


 (at 'label' 

with value '@string/title_activity_form').

DisplayingBitmaps/Application/build/
intermediates/manifests/full/debug/AndroidManifest.xml


 Error:Execution failed for task 

':Application:processDebugResources'.

> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: 

org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: 

Process 'command 'Android/Sdk/build-tools/23.0.3/aapt'' 

finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

.......................................................................

Okay, I updated Strings.xml, my very last errors:

Here's my Form.java

```
public class Form extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_form);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        //Initialize buttons and Edit Texts for form
        Button btnSubmit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_submit);
        Button btnSrc = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSrc);
        final EditText name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        final EditText email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        final EditText phone = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText4);

        //Listener on Submit button
        btnSubmit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent sender = new Intent(Form.this, com.chalkstreet.learnandroid.main.Display.class);
                Bundle b1 = new Bundle(); //Bundle to wrap all data
                b1.putString("name", name.getText().toString()); //Adding data to bundle
                b1.putString("email", email.getText().toString());
                b1.putString("phone", phone.getText().toString());
                sender.putExtras(b1); //putExtras method to send the bundle
                startActivity(sender);
                Form.this.finish(); //Finish form activity to remove it from stack
            }
        });

        //Listener on source button
        btnSrc.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent j = new Intent(Form.this, MainSource.class);
                startActivity(j);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == android.R.id.home) {

            Form.this.finish();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

**Here's the errors it gives me:**

```
Error:(18, 32) error: cannot find symbol variable activity_form

Error:(33, 88) error: package com.chalkstreet.learnandroid.main does not exist

Error:(48, 50) error: cannot find symbol class MainSource

Error:(57, 41) error: cannot find symbol variable menu_main
```

Comment: Do you have those 2 colors in your `colors.xml` file?

Comment: No, I don't actually. I suppose that might be missing. How about for source_but reference.

Comment: I appreciate your help also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `colors.xml` file you need to define:

```
<color name="background">#FF0000</color>
<color name="primary_dark">#00FF00</color>
```

(Change the values with the colors that your want)

---

Then you need to add the file `source_but` to your `drawable` folder.
If it is an image just move it there.

Comment: The last error happens because you need to define `<string name="title_activity_form">Title</string>`
 in your `strings.xml` file

Comment: Define all the things that are missing, follow the same procedure

Comment: i'm not sure what the need is for the package? its just a simple form

Comment: ill try to import it as i havent been doing

Comment: Try removing the package, you don't need it to reference a class

Comment: Intent sender = new Intent(Form.this,    Where do I send stuff? )

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114490/discussion-between-newton-and-juan-cruz-soler).